# Object pool - creating the objects later isnt working

Tags: c++, performance, memory-management, vector, object-pooling

My aim is to create a vector containing many pre-prepared (I dont have the two data members until later on but I want to allocate as much as I can in continuous memory) instances of my object in continuous memory and then later on in my program I can quickly use one of these prepared "shells" to instantiate my object quicker. Most importantly all of these objects will be located in the same continuous memory addresses.

To achieve the above I did this:

```
vector<MyClass*>* v = new vector<MyClass>();
v.reserve(10000);

//Later on....

// I want to create my object in the continuous memory I "reserved" 
// and have a variable name to it:

v->push_back(MyClass m(10,20));
process(m);
```

But I cannot get it to compile whilst still having a variable name on the object.... here is MyClass:

```
class MyClass{
    public:
        MyClass();
        MyClass(int a, int b);
        MyClass(const MyClass& m);
        int a;
        int b;
    private:
    //Made above example simpler by putting everything public
}
```

Comment: `vector v = new vector` thats Java. Also note in the second line you are using dot (`.`) instead of `->`

Answer (score 0):

I do object pooling, but I don't try to allocate them in contiguous memory, because this is not about memory caching, it is about minimizing calls to `new` and `delete`.

I keep used objects in a free-list.
When I no longer need one, I push it in the free-list.
Then when I need one I just pop one off the free-list.
If the free-list is empty, that's when I `new` a new one.